# Openstack Octavia Loadbalancer Security Group Support

Tags: openstack

We use openstack octavia loadbalancer on OpenStack Zed version. When I create loadbalancer, Octavia create 2 Amphora instance on service project and these amphora instances has two networks(lb management and my another tenant network.) If I wanna use healcheck on Octavia LoadBalancer. My amphora instances can't access my instance at another project. Because I should add amphora ip or all network cidr on my instance's security group. But I think this is the wrong solution because Amphora instances can failover and it takes different ip address. I should use amphora's security group on my another project. But I can not see amphora security groups on my another projects. Because  that security group on service project. Do you have any suggestion for me? What is the best solution?

Comment: I think in essence your question is how to manage security when you use the loadbalancer service in one project to load balance to one or more instances running in another project. - Security groups from one project are not available in another, I would hope, so you can't really use that for access control. - I can't test now but I would expect that health checks made to those external instances originate will from the VIP IP-address  that is assigned to your listener and not a random IP-address that changes each time an amphora instances fails over, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: So you can simply create a security rule that contains the load balancer VIP-address.

Comment: Unfortunately, Amphora uses the instance IP address, not VIP.(I tested it with tcpdump.)